# i have problem when i use binary attribute in sql statement where is error

Tags: php, html

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BINARY NOT NULL
>   )' at line 4

```
CREATE TABLE `img` (
  `idm` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `ido` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nameg` blob BINARY NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: There's no `BINARY` attribute for BLOB.

Comment: Blobs are always binary, that's the difference from TEXT.